# I can't run my android app using SwarmConnect

Tags: android

First, I created a new app, called it Test App (just for testing purpose)

Then I followed this guide (correctly) : http://swarmconnect.com/admin/docs/setup and http://swarmconnect.com/admin/docs/leaderboard (I just want to test the High Score implementation)

This is my MainActivity

```
package com.piavgh.testswarm;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.swarmconnect.Swarm;
import com.swarmconnect.SwarmActivity;
import com.swarmconnect.SwarmLeaderboard;

public class MainActivity extends SwarmActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Swarm.init(this, 7645, "c7b4ec126fc16f45c5fc9e6b3be09075");
        SwarmLeaderboard.submitScore(11783, 11); //submit the score 11 to server
        SwarmLeaderboard.showLeaderboard(11783);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I got the following error :

> E/AndroidRuntime(4404): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.piavgh.testswarm/com.piavgh.testswarm.MainActivity}:
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.piavgh.testswarm/com.swarmconnect.SwarmMainActivity}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Because SwarmConnect is just a library so it has no SwarmMainActivity! Anyone know the answer?

Thank you! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `SwarmMainActivity` in your manifest file.
It may be possible that `SwarmMainActivity` is getting called internally.

Comment: I know Eclispe error said that. But Swarm is a library, I can't find SwarmMainActivity in the src folder

Comment: You can check jar of Swarm library for SwarmMainActivity.

Comment: thank you! it's worked, now it's show me the login page and after login I can see the leaderboard.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line below to your project.properties

```
manifestmerger.enabled=true
```

In your manifest

> android:minSdkVersion="9"